# What's the difference between soft freeze and hard freeze?

Tags: release-management

The Release schedules show two freeze dates: Soft and Hard freeze. What's the difference between Soft Freeze and Hard Freeze?

Answer (score 1):

Soft freeze is equivalent to feature complete. Feature teams are expected to stop feature development and only commit bug fixes to release branches in the soft-freeze state.

A hard freeze is equivalent to dev complete.  All development for a release in hard freeze stops so release candidates can be built and tested for stability.  Any P2 or lower bugs will need to wait until the following release to be fixed.  Any P1 bugs found in the hard freeze release will need a post-code freeze ticket opened and approved before a fix can be added to the hard freeze release branch

Postcode freeze Ticket cab be created here: https://jira.walmart.com/servicedesk/customer/portal/2902/create/6615